# how can i set my homepage route? not "/" using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I just depolyed my website and I've been trying to set my website homepage route

I added "homepage" : "/auth" in my package.json before I deploy my website

it worked perfectly when I type localhost:3000 on searchbar I can see localhost:3000/auth page.

but now it doesn't work

I just want to see my authpage of my website when I type my domain like

mydomainname.com and then  => I will see mydomainname.com/auth

is this impossible? I'm using firebase hosting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/auth" /> <-- I added it but didn't work for me 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Post your life!" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="/manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>VCMemories</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage" : "/auth", <-- works fine when I'm doing in local but on online doesn't work.
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.38",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cloudinary-react": "^1.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.1",
    "react-full-page": "^0.1.12",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.15.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.6",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.13.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}
```

thanks for reading my qeustion

Answer (score 0):

using react-router-dom you can solve this.

Example code :

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function App(props) {

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
           <Redirect to="/auth" />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  )
}
export default App;
```

[***More Info***](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)